# Does "tar" follow either the POSIX and/or GNU command line options conventions?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, tar, command-line-arguments

[`tar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) is one of those venerable programs that is literally on every single UNIX-like system out there. There is POSIX-compliant `tar` and there is [GNU `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/).

A [typical way](https://xkcd.com/1168/) to use `tar` is a command like `tar -czf archive.tar.gz dir`. The option `-c` is to create a new archive, `-z` is to compress, and `-f` specifies the output filename. Note how `-c` and `-z` don't have arguments but `-f` does.

[This page](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Processing-command-line-options.html) describes the POSIX and GNU command line conventions. Note the following:

> Multiple options may follow a hyphen in a cluster if they **do not take
>   arguments**. Thus, -abc and -a -b -c are the same.

Does this mean that `tar`'s command line arguments handling does not conform to neither the POSIX nor GNU conventions? Or am I misreading something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't misreading, Unix `tar` follows neither the POSIX nor the GNU standard.

When it appeared in Unix version 7, `tar` first arguments was defined as a key composed of one function letter (one of `c r t u` and `x`) followed by optional function modifiers. All of them are single letters and there must be no embedded space. Some of the function modifiers require a parameter which must appear in the following arguments, in the order of the modifiers.

Later, `tar` implementations did allow a hyphen as a prefix for the whole key, or one hyphen for the single function letters but the convention of having the parameters separated at the end of the function letters was kept for the last option (usually `f`), allowing it to have its own parameter.

Moreover, GNU tar supports three option styles, the old one with the initial key followed by key arguments, the single letter option syntax which is like the POSIX standard way of passing arguments, and the long option style where word options are introduced by two dashes.

GNU `tar` allows these syntaxes (beyond many others) for the same command:

```
tar czvbf 20 archive.tar.gz dir
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz  -b 20 dir
tar -c -z -v -b 20 -f archive.tar.gz dir
tar --create --gzip --verbose --blocking-factor=20 --file=archive.tar.gz dir
tar --create --gzip --verbose --blocking-factor=20 --file archive.tar.gz dir
```

Combining different styles is possible with GNU tar but might produce unexpected results due to the variation in parsing rules.

Having fully converted from the original to the POSIX options standard syntax might have severely break compatibility with existing scripts using `tar`. That is probably one of the reasons the `tar` command wasn't standardized at all by POSIX and `pax`, which supports a POSIX standardized `tar` file format, was created.

Note that a similar issue exists with `ps`, which has two incompatible syntaxes, the BSD one (hyphenless) and the Unix one (with hyphens).

Comment: Good history lesson. Thanks.